# How to get the type of a column in Sybase ASE using SQL

Tags: sql, sybase, sap-ase

What SQL can I use to get the type of a column in Sybase ASE?

Answer (score 1):

Within any database you could use special stored procedure

```
sp_columns '<tableName>', null, null, '<colName>'
```

and of course, to  display all columns with extensive info about them for given table:

```
sp_columns '<tableName>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Given a table named "fruit" and a column named "color":

```
select obj.name as "table", col.name as "column", type.name as "type"
  from sysobjects obj
  join syscolumns col on obj.id=col.id
  join systypes type on col.type=type.type and col.usertype = type.usertype
 where obj.type = "U"               -- means 'U'ser table
   and user_name(obj.uid) = 'dbo'   -- or whatever the user is who owns/created the table
   and obj.name = 'fruit' 
   and col.name = 'color'
```